# Click event on div to get innerText value and $emit with event-bus to another component not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of divs that include product information which i get from an API call. In another component/view i want to display a single product information when the divs are clicked on.

So what i'm trying to do is retrieve the product id by accessing the event object when clicking on the divs then store that id in a variable (not data property) and then $emit it with the event-bus and then listen for it in my other component and use that id to make the API call to get the information for that single product. I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing what i want to do, but its the only way that comes to mind right now.

However so far i have gotten a few different errors and my component that displays the single product does not render.

This is the component that displays the list of products/divs

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="pagination">
      <button :disabled="disabled" @click.prevent="prev()">
        <i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i>
      </button>
      <span class="page-number">{{ currentPage }}</span>
      <button @click.prevent="next()">
        <i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="products">
      <div
        class="product"
        @click="getSingleBeer($event)"
        v-for="product in products"
        :key="product.id"
      >
        <h2 class="name">{{ product.name }}</h2>
        <div class="image">
          <img :src="product.image_url" />
        </div>
        <h3 class="tagline">{{ product.tagline }}</h3>
        <h3 class="first-brewed">{{ product.first_brewed }}</h3>
        <h3 class="abv">{{ product.abv }}%</h3>
        <p class="id">{{ product.id }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { eventBus } from "../main";

export default {
  name: "Products",
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      currentPage: 1,
      searchVal: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getBeers();

    eventBus.$on("keyword", val => {
      this.searchVal = val;

      this.getBeersForSearch();
    });
  },
  computed: {
    apiUrl() {
      return `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${this.currentPage}&per_page=16`;
    },
    apiUrlForSearch() {
      return `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${this.currentPage}&per_page=12&beer_name=${this.searchVal}`;
    },
    disabled() {
      return this.currentPage <= 1;
    },
    isFirstPage() {
      return this.currentPage === 1;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getBeers() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(this.apiUrl);

        this.products = response.data;

        console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    async getBeersForSearch() {
      try {
        this.currentPage = 1;

        const response = await axios.get(this.apiUrlForSearch);

        this.products = response.data;

        console.log(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
     getSingleBeer($event) {
      const id = parseInt($event.target.lastChild.innerText);
      eventBus.$emit("beer-id", id);
      this.$router.push({ name: "Beer" });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And this is the component/view that is going to display info for the single selected product.

```
<template>
  <div class="beer-container">
    <div class="description">
      <h2>{{ beer.description }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="img-name">
      <h1>{{ beer.name }}</h1>
      <img :src="beer.image_url" alt />
    </div>
    <div class="ingredients"></div>
    <div class="brewer-tips">
      <h2>{{ beer.brewers_tips }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from "../main";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Beer",
  data() {
    return {
      beerId: null,
      beer: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    eventBus.$on("beer-id", id => {
      this.beerId = id;
      this.getBeer();
      console.log(this.beer);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async getBeer() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(this.apiUrl);

        this.beer = response.data[0];

        console.log(response.data[0]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error + "Eroorrrrrr");
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    apiUrl() {
      return `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${this.beerId}`;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Some of the errors i had so far:
1-the api call is made 2-3 simultaneously when i observe console logs instead of just once.

```
GET https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/null 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400Eroorrrrrr
GET https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/null 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400Eroorrrrrr
GET https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/null 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400Eroorrrrrr
```

2-The first time i click on the div it directs to the new route/component but i dont receive any errors and nothing seems to happen behind the scenes.
3- I have also been getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null"
And
TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
```

My router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
import Beer from "./views/Beer.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/beer",
      name: "Beer",
      component: Beer
    }
  ]
});
```

UPDATE: I'm able to pass the data to the next component but when i click on the product divs the first time nothing happens, i only get directed to the next route/component but data does not get passed. And when i go back and click again,(without refreshing the page) the data gets passed but nothing renders on the component.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simplify that a lot by changing your @click to be:

```
@click="getSingleBeer(product.id)"
```

Which should pass the id for you, so you can just do:

```
getSingleBeer(beerId) {
    eventBus.$emit("beer-id", beerId);
    this.$router.push({ name: "Beer" });
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the suggestion. I can't believe i didn't think of getting the id this way instead of doing it in the silly way i was trying. I tried what you suggested and it works in that im successfully receiving the id in the other component. When i console logged everything it seems like a similar pattern is emerging in that in the first try after reloading the page the id is getting logged on the other end but no api call happens. Then when i go to the previous page (without refreshing) then the api call triggers but it returns a error.

Comment: when i console logged ```console.log(this.beer, this.beerId);``` i got this result ```{__ob__: Observer} 2``` which shows the id is there but not the object for the product and each time i go back to the main page and click on the divs again the request keep compounding.

Comment: Yes, you are only passing the id, not the product, you could just make it @click="getSingleBeer(product)" and getSingleBeer(beer) {
    eventBus.$emit("beer", beer);
    this.$router.push({ name: "Beer" });
}

Comment: Oh My dear Lord.....I can get the id, which means i can also get that whole product instead of making seperate api call in my other component. I believe that is what you're saying? :)

Comment: Indeed.  Way easier than playing around with $event.target.lastChild.innerText and ajax calls and things! ;)

Comment: I haven't slept for 3 days lol but regardless i don't know how to thank you Matt :) Everything is as smooth as butter now, but i don't know why my new component is not rendering/mounting...

Comment: I have no problem passing the product into the next route/component now, but i still have 2 small problems, 1-when i refresh the main page, on the first click nothing happens just like before and 2-my 'Beer' component doesn't render at all for some reason